# Nginx webapp conf creation automation

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, automation, certbot

When I start a new CMS project, say, a WordPress project, I need to create a new webapp with this template:

```
server {
    root ${drt}/${domain};
    server_name ${domain} www.${domain};
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
        try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php*-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
}
```

I then run:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain}.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
certbot --nginx -d ${domain} -d www.${domain}
```

Even though I do all of that from a script that I myself wrote and maintain, I would like to automate this process.

What could be a good way to automate this?

Comment: What is left to automate? I mean what is that you want to do? You have two lines of command only here, you can either put them in a bash script and call it

Comment: 2 lines of command?... `location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }` is not a default conf, and besides, AFAIK I also need `location / {}` and `location ~ \.php$ {}` inside **each** conf file.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155808/dry-virtual-web-server-configurations/46159390#46159390, if not then you should use some templating engine like https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd

Comment: Hmm I thank you for the links.